# Installing Ubuntu on a MacBook Air 7,2 keeping MacOs recovery

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 17.10, macbook

I am currently running macOs High Sierra on a MBA Early 2015 (7,2) and I would like to install Ubuntu on it as main, only OS.

Is there any way to **install Ubuntu** (17.10 at this moment, but any recent version will do) **and at the same time keeping the current macOs Recovery** (or Internet Recovery) **utilities** so that can be launched someway in the future in the case I need to recover macOs?

I have already a bootable USB drive to do the recovery task but would prefer to have macOs hidden somewhere in the SSD.

In case it is not possible, how do I boot my bootable USB?

I am very familiar to BIOS and Linux in PC but I have just got this laptop and I know nothing about how Recovery/UEFI/Whathever work in a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Option button as you start the Macbook with the bootable USB drive in it. Choose "EFI boot" and then "Try Ubuntu". You will see an "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop with which you can install to the disk partition you created under OS X. During the install procedure, choose "Something else" and make that partition Ext4, root. Click Install.

Now you can dual boot by holding down the Option key during boot.

This works fine on my Macbook Pro 11,4 with OS X High Sierra and Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Downvote because he asked specifically how to install ubuntu as an *only* OS, keeping only recovery.

Comment: You made a quick conclusion but my setup actually directly boots into Ubuntu and OSX can be removed as any other partition with ease. Only reason I kept it is to avoid having to reimburse my company for the MacBook should I need to return it.